# Persistent database connetion across resque workers

Tags: database, postgresql, sinatra, resque

I'm setting up a sinatra app which spawns resque workers to perform inserts on the database.

I don't want each worker to have to open and close a new connection.

How can I have each worker perform inserts on the DB without opening its own connection? Or is opening a connection a safe thing to do rapidly and in parallel?

Comment: @Bricholas probably update to redis server might help as I think the connection for the fork are reconnect if lost implicitly by redis that what I found out

Comment: @Bricholas Correct if I'm wrong DB over here is redis or some relational database

Comment: It's a relational DB, that's why I figure it would be expensive to open and close the connection.

Comment: you can use `reconnect` in mysql config it will reconnect the mysql Database automatically or create a new database connection for the job in `after_fork` hook of resque as suggest in the github page of resque as resque is using `fork` and fork would share everything from it child even the `mysql` connection so the parent connection would be close after the child fork `exit`

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the `https://github.com/samgranieri/resque-jobs-per-fork` gem to have each worker process more than one job, which increases efficiency rather than having each worker setup and tear down. `resque-jobs-per-fork` is a roundabout way of persisting connections.